# open webpage (or snapshot of webpage) into another webpage though vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url, web

i have an aspx page with vb.net back end. in that page i get names and url's from the database depending on different conditions. My requirement is that when i get the url, the code should then use that url and have that webpage in a small preview form on my existing aspx page.
so basically i have a table as follows -

Name   URL                     Preview-URL
Sandy  www.myspace.com/sandy   -- should be the url webpage in specified height and width.
Mandy  www.myspace.com/mandy   -- should be the url webpage in specified height and width.

does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create small url previews by using the [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp) tag.  Let's say you have an `asp:PlaceHolder` control called "iframePlaceholder" in your aspx.  In your code behind you could do something like:

```
Dim iframeControl As New LiteralControl("<iframe src=""www.myspace.com/mandy"" width=""100px"" height=""300px"">")
iframePlaceholder.Controls.Add(iframeControl)
```